# how to set max width to javascript pop-up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, css

The html code below results in a link which says "sacola the compras"

```
<div> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://app.ecwid.com/script.js?4549118"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
xMinicart("style=","layout=Mini"); 
</script> 
</div>
```

If you click the link, a pop-up window appear (it's not a pop-up per say, as it appears in the original window).
My problem with the pop-up is that it is not responsive. If I use an iPad or iPhone, the pop-up window will exceed the screen size.

For you to check the problem, please enter this [website](https://fernando-lurtz.squarespace.com/) and click in `visitor access`. Then click in the link which says "sacola de compras"

How do I limit the pop-up width? Does it have to do with the `xMinicart` function above?

Not sure if it helps, but here is the [javascript](https://app.ecwid.com/script.js?4549118) from the code above

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use `max-width`

Either in your CSS

```
.ecwid-popup {
    max-width: 200px;
}
```

Or inline, in your HTML

```
<div class="ecwid-popup ecwid-ProductBrowserPopup ecwid" style="max-width: 200px;">
```

Comment: it does resize the window, but the window only - the content exceeds the now resized window. maybe there is another div we should target as well?

Comment: if that's the case, you may want to add similar code to the inner elements.  You can also use `width: inherit` on those inner elements if you simply want them to be the same size as the outer div.

Answer (score 0):

Ecwid will eventually make that popup-like window responsive so that it will work fine on any device. Meanwhile, I can suggest a workaround: although it does not make the popup responsive, it will allow you to avoid popup and display the cart contents on a separate responsive page that will look fine on mobile devices. The workaround is using Ecwid's `ecwid_ProductBrowserURL` option like this:

```
 <script> var ecwid_ProductBrowserURL = "http://www.example.com/my_separate_store_page.html"; </script>
```

With this option used, a visitor who clicks the minicart icon, will be automatically redirected to a responsive cart page. Find the details on how to implement it here: http://kb.ecwid.com/w/page/15853260/ecwid_ProductBrowserURL